# How to keep LineFeed in GuzzleHttp Response Body

Tags: php, csv, curl, guzzle

I am doing and cUrl request using Guzzle.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
    $response = $client->get($url);
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $ex) {
    // handle error.
}
```

The server response is formatted like this:

```
"field1","field2","field3"\n
"value1","value2","value3"\n
"value4","","value5"\n
```

Using GuzzleHttp\Client, I receive the following response body

```
"field1","field2","field3""value1","value2","value3""value4","","value5"\n
```

Is it possible to set the Guzzle Client not to replace line feed chars in the response body?

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know what your response looks like.
2. We don't know how you are viewing the response.

In the presence of these two details I would have to guess that you might have to implement some type of [stream decorator](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/streams.html#stream-decorators) so that only single lines of the response are read in at a time.